# ng- message is not displaying message properly

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, ng-messages

I am doing validation using angular js and trying to display error messages through ng-message directive. But my issue is that in my form when I enter any error input , it does not display message at first time  and when I click anywhere outside the form then only its displaying messages.Also I want that when error is removed then original label should appear. But here once error message is shown , then label don't appear in my form. I am using below code for validation-

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.num.$invalid && (myForm.$submitted  || myForm.num.$touched ) || myForm.num.$error.minlength || myForm.num.$error.maxlength || myForm.num.$error.pattern}">

    <label for="Number" style="color:#767676" class=""
           ng-hide="myForm.num.$invalid && (myForm.$submitted  || myForm.num.$touched || myForm.num.$error.minlength || myForm.num.$error.pattern)">Number</label>

    <div ng-show="myForm.num.$touched " ng-messages="myForm.num.$error">
        <label class="error_message_text" ng-message="required">required field</label>
        <label class="error_message_text" ng-message="minlength">too short</label>
        <label class="error_message_text" ng-message="pattern">wrong pattern</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="text" numbers-only name="num" class="form-control" ng-class="" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="9"
           ng-model="user.name" ng-pattern="/^\d{7}$|^\d{9}$/" required/>

</div>
```

I have created a plunker here- 
https://plnkr.co/edit/tYDdIs8ZhrdjSko68Wkh?p=preview

Can anyone help me in my validation where I am missing?

Comment: Did you check my updated answer and plnkr?

Comment: @Aanchal See the updated plunkr

Comment: @Aanchal Updated my answer again... please check it.

Comment: Done @Aanchal See my plunker

Comment: @Aanchal, if want to fire event on tab key press, you should write your own directive. SO is Q&A site for coding problem, not help forum. Your question is too broad to answer. Even you did not mention your requirements properly..

Comment: @ Khalid, I have got what I wanted as per my requirement, see the the final answer plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both dirty and error valid,

```
 <div ng-show="myForm.num.$invalid && myForm.$submitted" ng-messages="myForm.num.$error">
```

See this plunker,but I have removed your number validation code that made problems during required validations
https://plnkr.co/edit/3m0zLJ2PhAruSFxStwmt?p=preview

Updated Final Answer-
https://plnkr.co/edit/v65oGQaZ64nU25EhX2nz?p=preview

Comment: But my label is disapperaing, when I tab out of my box .After that if I remove the value after entering something ,then  label dont appear. what condition is required for label to appear whenever there is no error message? @ Shintu

Comment: There is a problem with your number validation for required leaving apart that, this validation will work when you click the submit button without valid input

Comment: Your code is showing error messages if I submit the form. I want apart from this feature, it should show error messages when I am tabbing out of the box. I mean in your form when I am entering any wrong value then it is not showing message untill and unless I submit it. Could u add any condition so that it will also show error message when I am tabbing out of it @ Shintu

Comment: @ Shintu, your code is working fine as per my requirement. Here I have done some small edit as box was moving up and down with error messages and edited the has error class- https://plnkr.co/edit/v65oGQaZ64nU25EhX2nz?p=preview

Comment: @DownVoters please comment the problem here

Comment: @ Shintu, your code is perfectly fine, if I want to add blur , Is there any way that first time when we are entering any value then it will show error on blur , and after that it works as usual as it is working now.

Comment: Remove the $dirty check and try

Comment: Yes, its working, I have updated my plunker-https://plnkr.co/edit/v65oGQaZ64nU25EhX2nz?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have added `ng-show="myForm.num.$touched "` to your error message container. The `$touched` will be true when you remove focus from an input field. That is why you are getting the error message after you are clicking outside.

Comment: fine, but what condition should I give so that label 'Number' will always appear when error is removed. currently, when I am tabbing out label dont appear  @Shashank

Comment: I don't understand if you don't want to hide the label at any condition, why you added `ng-hide` there? Is there specific reason?

Comment: I want to hide the label only when error messages are coming. so what condition I need to  give ?

Answer (score 1):

[**Update 2 Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ck4xG23lHxZwgj9qEnrz?p=preview)

Use `$dirty` instead of `$touched`. So your code should look like this:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.num.$dirty " ng-messages="myForm.num.$error">
```

**Update**

`Number` label should look like this:

Number

Remove if condition from `numbersOnly` directive.

```
.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {

                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;  

            }            
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
```

Show validation message with following code:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.num.$dirty || myForm.$submitted" ng-messages="myForm.num.$error">
            <label class="error_message_text" ng-message="required">required field</label>
             <label class="error_message_text" ng-message="minlength">too short</label>
             <label class="error_message_text" ng-message="pattern">wrong pattern</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Error is fine now, but when I am tabbing out after getting error and again enter the correct value then the original label is not appearing, i mean 'Number ' is not shown once I tab out of the box. what condition is missing for it?

Comment: It is not showing 'required' message when textbox is empty. Also once I submit the form, then again label disappears @Khalid

Comment: @Aanchal Updated my answer, please check it... also updated the plnkr. Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: but it is not showing error messages when I am entering some value and tabbing out. Its working only when I am submitting the form. Apart from this, I want it should give error messages when I am tabbing out. @Khalid

Comment: @Aanchal What do you mean by "tabbing out"? I see it's working properly. I tried to answer your question. I recommend you to have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question.

Comment: With tabbing out I mean, when I click inside the box than I click outside , it should show error- required, but it is not showing. Also when I am clicking on submitting button without entering any value then it is showing error message as well as label 'Number' both at the same time. it should not show label name when error messages are shown.

Comment: @Aanchal 1. Which DEMO are you checking? Have a look at this [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/rju6nAriTJgkS3V7s9TI?p=preview). 2) Can you please have a look at your earlier comment? `It is not showing 'required' message when textbox is empty. Also once I submit the form, then again label disappears`

Comment: You are messing up your requirement. That's why I told you to [edit] your question and provide specific requirements.